# Executorservice Check All the task are done

Tags: java

I want to check if all the executor service task are done before submitting the new batch of task
here is my code:

```
     ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrency);
     for(int i=0;i<batch;i++){      
  
        for(int j=0;j<concurrency;j++) {
            executorService.submit(new DOTASK(0,loopTimes));
        }
      
        while(executorService != done){
                    // wait
             }
            System.out.println("Batch "+i+"Complete")

        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Comment: You can use `CountDownLatch` or `join()`

Comment: You can wait with `awaitTermination()`, just as you already did. What is the problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

**[CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)** is an option for you

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrency);
for(int i=0;i<batch;i++){      

    CountLatchDown latch = new CountDownLatch(concurrency);
    for(int j=0;j<concurrency;j++) {
        executorService.submit(new DOTASK(0,loopTimes));
    }
    //in each DOTASK thread invoke latch.countDown()
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Batch "+i+"Complete")

}
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```